# How to set device owner on Android Things?

Tags: android, android-things, device-policy-manager, device-owner, android-device-owner

I would like to set my Android app as device owner on a device running Android Things.

(I know that Android Things is getting shut down, but still I would need to make it work)

I tried the usual command: `adb shell dpm set-device-owner <package>/<component>`

This command works well on a standard Android device, but on Android Things I get the following response:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't set package ComponentInfo{<package>/<component>} as device owner.
at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.runSetDeviceOwner(Dpm.java:149)
at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.onRun(Dpm.java:96)
at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:54)
at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.main(Dpm.java:41)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:285)
```

I tried running the command as root (after `adb shell` & `su`), but still get the same error.

I also tried to create manually `device_owner.xml`, `device_policies.xml`,... files in `/system/data`, as mentionned in topics related to AOSP, but it has no effect.

Is it somehow possible to set device owner on an Android Things device?

Comment: Does the `AndroidManifest.xml` export the `receiver`? While actually, they'll shut down the Things console on January 5, 2022... https://developer.android.com/things/faq

Comment: @MartinZeitler Yes, that actually works on a standard Android system, but not on Android Things. I know that Android Things is getting shut down, but still I would need to make it work...

Answer (score 0):

Android Things are already deprecated now, you can use smartphone OS or Android. That is based on this [quote](https://www.infoq.com/news/2020/12/google-terminates-android-things/):

> Android Things is a now-deprecated Android-based embedded operating system platform by Google, announced at Google I/O 2015, and launched in 2018. In 2019, Android Things dropped support for low-power hardware and refocused on smartphone-class devices.

Owner in android can be used to set in this document [explanation](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/build-dpc), sample code :

```
val provisioningActivity = getActivity()

// You'll need the package name for the DPC app.
val myDPCPackageName = "com.example.myDPCApp"

// Set up the provisioning intent
val provisioningIntent = Intent("android.app.action.PROVISION_MANAGED_PROFILE")
provisioningIntent.putExtra(myDPCPackageName,
        provisioningActivity.applicationContext.packageName)
if (provisioningIntent.resolveActivity(provisioningActivity.packageManager) == null) {
    // No handler for intent! Can't provision this device.
    // Show an error message and cancel.
} else {
    // REQUEST_PROVISION_MANAGED_PROFILE is defined
    // to be a suitable request code
    startActivityForResult(provisioningIntent,
            REQUEST_PROVISION_MANAGED_PROFILE)
    provisioningActivity.finish()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But my question explicitely targets Android Things (even though it's deprecated).

Comment: @sdabet, I think you can find alternative android things repo contribution